# Ember version 2.12.2: view isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am writing a research paper and as a part of it I am doing a performance benchmark between Ember's KVO change detection method and React's Virtual DOM change detection method.

I made 2 identical applications - one with Ember and one with React, but I realized afterwards that I've used an old version of ember(1.8.0). I am now trying to change and refactor it to version 2.12.2.

For now I replaced ObjectControllers with Controllers.

Now the problem is - when application is initialized, there should be a link that when pressed shows tweet list. Now with v2.12.2. the link is not shown, I am not getting any error messages.

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <a class="label label-default" href="#/list">SHOW LIST</a>
        {{outlet}}
    </script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the v2.12.2 version of this app, which does not work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nLqr2w/6/)

Here is a fiddle of the v1.8.0 version of this app, which works [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nLqr2w/7/)

Any hints on where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a combination of JSFiddle loading resources in the wrong order plus invalid HTML in your Handlebars template. Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nLqr2w/10/).

Basically, I moved the Ember.js files from "External Resources"  into  tags, and then corrected an unclosed `<div>` and a closing `</img>` (which is invalid).

Also, please note that `{{bind-attr}}` is [deprecated](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/)